# Throwing OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I followed an online video of how to make a tabbed app on android. On the video it works fine but I am getting this error and cant find any solution.

This is a so basic app that the error does not make sense. The app is just 3 empty fragments and a main activity. I don't even have any data. The error doesn't even report any line of my code!

```
    01-21 15:58:47.474 2382-2382/com.laiq.laiq E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 23700984 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 18MB until OOM"
01-21 15:58:47.478 2382-2382/com.laiq.laiq E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23700984 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 18MB until OOM
                                                                 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
                                                                 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
                                                                 at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
                                                                 at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
                                                                 at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
                                                                 at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
                                                                 at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
                                                                 at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
                                                                 at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:340)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:85)
                                                                 at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                 at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

This is my main class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // List of all fragments
        List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        mFragmentList.add(new NewsFragment());
        mFragmentList.add(new OffersFragment());
        mFragmentList.add(new ProductsFragment());

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragmentList);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

//        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
//            }
//        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I tried to look at other answers but this doesn't make sense, where am I requesting any memory?

My SectionsPagerAdapter

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        List<Fragment> listFragments;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> listFragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.listFragments = listFragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return listFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return listFragments.size();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are causing a stack overflow, and it doesn't have enough memory to report the exception...

Comment: There is nothing much to cause an OOM. But what is your device? It seems a very low ram device and there is not actually enough memory. See only 16MB is free

Comment: Try quitting all other open apps, restart the phone, and run it again - but something this small should surely be fine to run on only 18MB?

Comment: @AmitK.Saha I used a Xperia Z2 and the android emulator. The error was the same.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I tried to restart the phone (for the phone testing) and the computer (for emulator) the error is the same...

Comment: can you post your SectionsPagerAdapter ??

Comment: @AmitK.Saha I added in the post. Hope you can help me!

Comment: sorry there is nothing in the adapter, I was hoping if it were leaking any memory from there. what if you just add fragment and one by one and see what happens. just to check if any particular fragment has any problem.